# Getting this ImportErrorcan "not import name fpn_pb2", when trying to run the training using tensor flow 2 object detection API

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

I am doing research in deep learning using Tensor flow 2 object detection API. I am getting this error while running the model training. I followed the Gilbert Tanner and Edje Electronics tutorial for basic installations and environment settings. I am using the TensorFlow object detection API new GitHub Commit. I converted the all .protos files into .py files but still facing this error. I am attaching a screenshot of this error. please check this and let me know if you can help.

Thanks in Advance. [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eErDT.png)

Comment: Can you provide links of the tutorials that you followed? Its also an import error so there could be problem with `PYTHONPATH`? Did you try anything to resolve the issue first?

Comment: https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10. this tutorial is for TensorFlow 1, but I did some changes by following different pages. yes I set the path but it's again giving me this error

Comment: Problem could be due to `tensorflow` version. Repeat the tutorial using tensorflow 1 to see whether it works for tensorflow 1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and also with `target_assigner.proto`, `center_net.proto`, you have to add all three `.\object_detection\protos\fpn.proto .\object_detection\protos\target_assigner.proto .\object_detection\protos\center_net.proto`
to protoc command. So whole command should be:

```
protoc --python_out=. .\object_detection\protos\anchor_generator.proto .\object_detection\protos\argmax_matcher.proto .\object_detection\protos\bipartite_matcher.proto .\object_detection\protos\box_coder.proto .\object_detection\protos\box_predictor.proto .\object_detection\protos\eval.proto .\object_detection\protos\faster_rcnn.proto .\object_detection\protos\faster_rcnn_box_coder.proto .\object_detection\protos\grid_anchor_generator.proto .\object_detection\protos\hyperparams.proto .\object_detection\protos\image_resizer.proto .\object_detection\protos\input_reader.proto .\object_detection\protos\losses.proto .\object_detection\protos\matcher.proto .\object_detection\protos\mean_stddev_box_coder.proto .\object_detection\protos\model.proto .\object_detection\protos\optimizer.proto .\object_detection\protos\pipeline.proto .\object_detection\protos\post_processing.proto .\object_detection\protos\preprocessor.proto .\object_detection\protos\region_similarity_calculator.proto .\object_detection\protos\square_box_coder.proto .\object_detection\protos\ssd.proto .\object_detection\protos\fpn.proto .\object_detection\protos\target_assigner.proto .\object_detection\protos\center_net.proto .\object_detection\protos\ssd_anchor_generator.proto .\object_detection\protos\string_int_label_map.proto .\object_detection\protos\train.proto .\object_detection\protos\keypoint_box_coder.proto .\object_detection\protos\multiscale_anchor_generator.proto .\object_detection\protos\graph_rewriter.proto .\object_detection\protos\calibration.proto .\object_detection\protos\flexible_grid_anchor_generator.proto
```